# How to make my long height image scroll bar visible and the image itsel visible

Tags: html, css

I have little website I'm trying to plan on building. But when I started making the background image for it, the image is made so my website is kind of scrolling web page up and down so I made it long. But now the image only shows small part of it, I trying changing resolution of my browser and I could see it but without that I cannot scroll to see the whole image.

The problem which shows that the photo is not fully shown, photo is 2160*3840 px means it is opposite of normal resolution:

[image]

Comment: Could you give us a screenshot of how your website looks currently so we can better understand what the issue is?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma i did edited it

Answer (score 1):

If you're using CSS and adding this as a background image to the page `body`, then it should be an easy problem to solve (and in fact you get quite a few options).

Firstly, lets assume this is your current code:

```
body {
    background-image:url("yourimage.png"); /* The filetype does not matter */
}
```

Now, as far as CSS sees it, some people viewing your site could be on phones, some on 13" laptops, or some could be viewing it on 5k desktops - if we want the image to work on all at all of these different sizes, then clearly the image is going to have to be modified in *some* way.

By adding the `background-size` property here, we can adjust how this happens:

- `background-size:cover;` seems like the best choice for you. It will slightly crop / stretch the image to fit it (but remember, this is probably going to be beneficial).
- `background-size:100% 100%;` will always display 100% of the image - but this will usually result in it being stretched, etc.

There are quite a few other values this property can be set to - you can take a look at them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=auto), or read the spec on it over at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size).

Comment: Thank you , i tried that already but the fact is that i made the photo in a 4k resolution so anyone from 720p to 4k screens can see it HD , even on phones * that is why it is long* + add that i will add some serious big amount of stuff in it , that why i need the scroll down aswell @Toastrackenigma - this is *contain & cover results - https://imgur.com/a/igdYnta